# Integrating facebook and google in same app and allow user to signin both simultaneously

Tags: android, facebook, google-plus, facebook-android-sdk, google-play-games

Is it possible to integrate both facebook and google in one app so as to in allow user to sign in for both ...  i.e use google game services for Real time multiplayer and then at the end, post the result on facebook  .. so in a manner where my app would hold both sessions fb as well as google ?? is thing this possible ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes of course , you can use [the google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) and [the facebook sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) in your API.
you begin by Login your users by googles+.
in the end, if the user wants to share anything in facebook you authenticate him with facebook sdk, then ask for permissions then publish what you want.
you can find many tutorials and samples about the authentication in google+ and facebook.

I don't want to give advertisements about libraries (and I didn't even test anyone of them...) , I hear about [GigyaSDK](http://developers.gigya.com/035_Mobile_SDKs/020_Android). they have a good documentation of integration.

Comment: Any library that takes care of both? Like [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth) for node.